# is there a way to monitor transactional replication latency without using tokens?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, database-replication

When I have latency on my replicated publications, I resort to adding a token and watch it.
Is there any way of troubleshooting replication latency without the use of tokens?
This is SQL Server 2005 - Transactional Replication.

Comment: Why not just post a token on a regular basis with sp_post_tracertoken? Then, you can look at the progress of all the tokens in replication monitor and know which one was last delivered, how long it took to get there, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out this link about [checking replication latency using T-SQL](http://sqlfool.com/2008/11/checking-replication-latency-with-t-sql/)
and created the procedure in my environment and it worked very nicely.

here is the code of the procedure, and in the comments, how I have utilized it.

```html
USE [MY_PUBLICATION_DATABASE]
-- this procedure is to be created inside the publication database
GO
Create Procedure dbo.dba_replicationLatencyGet_sp

        /* Declare Parameters */
          @publicationToTest sysname        = N'yourPublicationName'
        , @replicationDelay  varchar(10)    = N'00:00:30'
        , @iterations        int            = 5
        , @iterationDelay    varchar(10)    = N'00:00:30'
        , @deleteTokens      bit            = 1
        , @deleteTempTable   bit            = 1
As
/*********************************************************************************
    Name:       dba_replicationLatencyGet_sp

    Author:     Michelle F. Ufford

    Purpose:    Retrieves the amount of replication latency in seconds

    Notes:      Default settings will run 1 test every minute for 5 minutes.

                @publicationToTest = change the default to your publication

                @replicationDelay = how long to wait for the token to replicate;
                    probably should not set to anything less than 10 (in seconds)

                @iterations = how many tokens you want to test

                @iterationDelay = how long to wait between sending test tokens
                    (in seconds)

                @deleteTokens = whether you want to retain tokens when done

                @deleteTempTable = whether or not to retain the temporary table
                    when done.  Data stored to ##tokenResults; set @deleteTempTable 
                    flag to 0 if you do not want to delete when done.

    Called by:  DBA
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Marcelo Miorelli
    01-Oct-2014 wednesday
    I found this wonderful procedure at this site:
    http://sqlfool.com/2008/11/checking-replication-latency-with-t-sql/

    I have tested it
    Server: SQLWEBLON1.DEV.BODEN.LOCAL
    DB: AUAccount

    I had to create the procedure in the Publisher database, and run it from there.

        Exec dbo.dba_replicationLatencyGet_sp
          @publicationToTest    = N'AUAccount'
        , @replicationDelay     = N'00:00:05'
        , @iterations           = 1
        , @iterationDelay       = N'00:00:05'
        , @deleteTokens         = 1
        , @deleteTempTable      = 1;

    "La observación y la percepción son dos cosas separadas; 
     el ojo que observa es más fuerte, el ojo que percibe es más débil. "
     "el libro de los 5 anillos" 
     Mushashi

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Date        Initials    Description
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2008-11-20   MFU        Initial Release
*********************************************************************************
    Exec dbo.dba_replicationLatencyGet_sp
          @publicationToTest    = N'yourPublicationName'
        , @replicationDelay     = N'00:00:05'
        , @iterations           = 1
        , @iterationDelay       = N'00:00:05'
        , @deleteTokens         = 1
        , @deleteTempTable      = 1;
*********************************************************************************/

Set NoCount On;
Set XACT_Abort On;

Begin

    /* Declare Variables */
    Declare @currentIteration   int
          , @tokenID            bigint
          , @currentDateTime    smalldatetime;

    If Object_ID('tempdb.dbo.##tokenResults') Is Null
    Begin
        Create Table ##tokenResults
                        ( iteration           int             Null
                        , tracer_id           int             Null
                        , distributor_latency int             Null
                        , subscriber          varchar(1000)   Null
                        , subscriber_db       varchar(1000)   Null
                        , subscriber_latency  int             Null
                        , overall_latency     int             Null );
    End;

    /* Initialize our variables */
    Select @currentIteration = 0
         , @currentDateTime  = GetDate();

    While @currentIteration < @iterations
    Begin

        /* Insert a new tracer token in the publication database */
        Execute sys.sp_postTracerToken 
          @publication = @publicationToTest,
          @tracer_token_id = @tokenID OutPut;

        /* Give a few seconds to allow the record to reach the subscriber */
        WaitFor Delay @replicationDelay;

        /* Store our results in a temp table for retrieval later */
        Insert Into ##tokenResults
        (
            distributor_latency
          , subscriber
          , subscriber_db
          , subscriber_latency
          , overall_latency
        )
        Execute sys.sp_helpTracerTokenHistory @publicationToTest, @tokenID;

        /* Assign the iteration and token id to the results for easier investigation */
        Update ##tokenResults
        Set iteration = @currentIteration + 1
          , tracer_id = @tokenID
        Where iteration Is Null;

        /* Wait for the specified time period before creating another token */
        WaitFor Delay @iterationDelay;

        /* Avoid endless looping... :) */
        Set @currentIteration = @currentIteration + 1;

    End;

    Select * From ##tokenResults;

    If @deleteTempTable = 1
    Begin
        Drop Table ##tokenResults;
    End;

    If @deleteTokens = 1
    Begin
       Execute sp_deleteTracerTokenHistory @publication = @publicationToTest, @cutoff_date = @currentDateTime;
    End;

    Set NoCount Off;
    Return 0;
End
Go
```

Answer (score 1):

You can roll your own solution by using and replicating a datetime column and updating it with the current timestamp every X minutes on the Publisher.  Then, on the Subscriber, you can run a job every X minutes and compare the datetime column value with the current time and alert if the difference is greater than X minutes.